# Two css3 columns text with an image in middle

Tags: html, css

I'd like to achieve this result

[image]

there are many tutorial around [like this](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/crosscolumn/) but they work with a fixed text and columns. I print a variable-length text inside my two column layout in this way

```css
#cols {
column-count: 2;
column-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <p id="cols">
    Lorem Ipsum....
  </p>
</div>
```

so I can't use a technique like that, how can I put an image in the middle in this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are:
http://jsfiddle.net/aX47K/

css:

```
.column{  
   width:300px;  
   float:left;  
   margin-right:20px;  
} 

.column div{  
  width:200px;  
  height:210px;  
}

#col-1 div{
  float:right;
}
#col-2 div{
 float:left;
} 

img#center-image{  
  position:absolute;  
  left:110px;
}
```

Comment: I figured that I can't and used the old solution.